# Xamarin Forms Master-Detail Page Menu

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, master-detail

I have a MainPage that has a MasterDetailPage I am using it to store the menupage control. The menu display but I am not able to navigating to the new page.

> Do I need to add a MasterDetailPage.Detail to the homePage.xaml?

[image: Menu Color]

MenuPage

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Spacing="10">
        <Label VerticalOptions="Center" Text="SideDrawer" />
    </StackLayout>
    <StackLayout VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <ListView x:Name="ListViewMenu"
                HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                        <Grid Padding="10">
                            <Label Text="{Binding Title}" FontSize="20"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackLayout>
</Grid>
public partial class MenuPage : ContentPage
{
    MainPage RootPage { get => Application.Current.MainPage as MainPage; }
    public NavigationPage Detail { get; private set; }
    List<HomeMenuItem> menuItems;
    public MenuPage ()
    {
        InitializeComponent ();
        menuItems = new List<HomeMenuItem>
        {
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Home, Title="Home" ,IconSource="Home.png", TargetType = typeof(Pages.HomePage)},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.Share, Title="Share App" ,IconSource="Home.png" ,TargetType = typeof(Pages.HomePage)},
            new HomeMenuItem {Id = MenuItemType.About, Title="About App",IconSource="Home.png",TargetType = typeof(Pages.HomePage) }
        };
        ListViewMenu.ItemsSource = menuItems;
        ListViewMenu.ItemSelected += OnItemSelected;
    }
    void OnItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var item = e.SelectedItem as HomeMenuItem;
        if (item != null)
        {
            //This will create instance of the page using the parameterized constructor you defined in each DetailPages
            Detail = new NavigationPage((Page)Activator.CreateInstance(item.TargetType));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you are assigning a local variable named Detail, this is NOT the same thing as the Detail property of your MasterDetail page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a page that inherits from `MasterDetailPage`. That will give you a **Detail** property to set and navigate properly.

I would suggest following this guide to help you out!

[Xamarin.Forms Master-Detail Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/master-detail-page)

Comment: is there a way I can change the color and add text?

Comment: What do you want to change the color of?

Comment: Sorry image didnt post, I wanted to change the color of the menu and add a title ?

Comment: The Master (drawer) page that includes your `ListView` with the pages to select, can have any sort of bar or text on it that you would like. Just modify the **MasterPageCS.xaml** that is used in the example. It contains a stacklayout that you can add other controls into easily.